# MWAA Airflow UI: Broken plugin[No module]

Tags: mwaa

I have created Airflow environment in MWAA. I have mentioned all the required modules in requirements.txt but getting 'Broken plugin: No module found' error in MWAA Airflow UI although Scheduler/worker logs show modules are installed successfully and dags using those modules are also working fine.

Does anyone have any idea, How to get rid of this error?

[UI Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0WEh.png)
[Scheduler logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjlLs.png)

Comment: Is the red error banner expandable? Can you show the full stack trace? What versions of the modules are installed?

Comment: with DAG(
        dag_id=DAG_ID,
        default_args=DEFAULT_ARGS,
        description='Print all installed Python packages',
        dagrun_timeout=timedelta(hours=2),
        start_date=days_ago(1),
        schedule_interval=None,
        tags=['bash']
) as dag:
    list_python_packages_operator = BashOperator(
        task_id='list_python_packages',
        bash_command='python3 -m pip list'
    )

list_python_packages_operator

Comment: Can you list the python packages using bash once and recheck